# Google Analytics and Second Dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

[image]

I get codes from a referral url that I place into a custom dimension when calling Universal Google Analytics which works with everything like Geo etc, but doesn't work with demographic data like **Age** in Analytics. Does anyone know how to make that work?

Working example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the scope of your dimension and age does not match
since age is a user level metrics it only allows user level custom dimension with it.

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML

Comment: Thank you for your response. It looks like it took another day to start showing up because of the dx ids passed off the first day did not have google analytics demo data associated with them. This morning when I checked there were a few (not a lot) dx ids connected to age groups. I'll have to run another test to see if changing the scope to user would render more. Thank you!

Comment: I've read somewhere that Age and certain other demographics are extracted from cookies and sessions of logged in users. ie. if you're logged into Google as you're browsing they use your profile to extract the age, sex etc... Need to investigate further.